# How to get Google places in model box

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-template, bootstrap-4

I have google places search in my model box.I am using angular 2.

```
 <input type="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" [ngClass]="{active:signupSubmitted && !signUpForm.controls['formatted_address'].valid}"
 [formControl]="signUpForm.controls['formatted_address']" [(ngModel)]="data.formatted_address"
       (setAddress)="getAddress($event)" googleplace/>
```

I also kept this in my css.

```
.pac-container {
   z-index: 1100 !important;
 }
```

But no use.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: update your working code in https://jsfiddle.net/ or codepen

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.pac-container {
    z-index: 1051 !important;
}
```

Comment: ,its not wrkng.